# Display one row per search term, subsitute default if not found

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Query:

```
SELECT product_id,
       name 
  FROM product 
 WHERE barcode in (681027, 8901030349379,
                   679046, 679047,
                   679082, 679228,
                   679230, 679235,
                   679236, 679238,
                   679328, 679330,
                   679528, 679608,
                   679609, 679647,
                   679727, 679728,
                   679730, 679808,
                   679809, 679828, 679830)
```

Output:

```
YES   -IF PRODUCT NAME IS PRESENT
NO    -IF PRODUCT NAME IS NOT PRESENT
NO
YES
YES
NO
...
```

How do I display if there is no row for the particular barcode? Is it good practice to use `IN` statement in sql?

I use PostgreSQL 8.2.11.

Comment: Many people here will tell you not to use `IN` but the truth of the matter is that many DBMS, including latest versions of MySQL, already transform `IN` to `EXISTS` automatically.

Comment: It is difficult for us help you without a little clearer idea for your desired result.

Comment: To "This worked for me" - this won't show products that *have* barcode. So it's nor exactly as requested "output" but you decide what is good for you :-).

Comment: You might want to disclose the version of PostgreSQL in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
select case when p.name is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end as barcode_exists, t.barcode
from product as p
right join (
    select 681027 as barcode union
    select 8901030349379 union
    select 679046 union
    select 679047 union
    select 679082 union
    select 679228 union
    select 679230 union
    select 679235 union
    select 679236 union
    select 679238 union
    select 679328 union
    select 679330 union
    select 679528 union
    select 679608
            -- all the rest barcodes
) as t on p.barcode = t.barcode
```

In `union` put all barcodes that you want to check.

**Aded:**

It returns two columns to match barcode and *answer* because you can't relay on rows order unless you specify one.

Comment: SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "p"
LINE 1: select if p.name is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end if as

Comment: @soul, corrected - check my edit. Sorry I work mostly on SQL Server - bit different syntax.

Comment: Powaga its postgre server  > the error i get now is SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1067: ) t on p.barcode= t.barcode

Comment: Try my last edit, hopefully `case` in PostgreSQL looks like in SQL Server :-).

Comment: SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1065:  select  9556006277096 union)as t on p.barcode= t.barcode

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4965/discussion-between-soul-and-michal-powaga)

Answer (score 1):

#### Since PostgreSQL 8.4

Use [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) and a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT x.barcode
     , p.product_id
     , CASE WHEN p.name IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS product_name_exists
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest (
         '{679046,679047,679082,679228,679230,679235,679236,'
          '679238,679328,679330,679528,679608,679609,679647,'
          '679727,679728,679730,679808,679809,679828,679830}'::text[]) AS barcode
         ) x
LEFT   JOIN product USING (barcode);
```

[`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) generates one row per array element. It was introduced with PostgreSQL 8.4.
[`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) ensures that every `barcode` shows up, even if no matching product is found.

Be aware that there can be two reasons for a "missing" product name (`NULL`):

1. No matching `product.barcode` is found.
2. `product.barcode` is found, but the `product.name` coming with it is `NULL`.

You may want to add a `NOT NULL` constraint to the column `name` in your table `product` - if you don't have one.

#### PostgreSQL 8.3

Use [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT x.barcode
     , p.product_id
     , CASE WHEN p.name IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS product_name_exists
FROM   (SELECT regexp_split_to_table (
              '679046,679047,679082,679228,679230,679235,679236,'
              '679238,679328,679330,679528,679608,679609,679647,'
              '679727,679728,679730,679808,679809,679828,679830', ',') AS barcode
         ) x
LEFT   JOIN product USING (barcode);
```

Note how strings listed on separate lines are concatenated automatically. A not so well known standard SQL feature.

#### PostgreSQL 8.2

None of the SET-generating functions exist, yet. **Consider upgrading** to a more recent version! PostgreSQL 8.2 is reaching [end of life in Dezember 2011](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Release_Support_Policy).

**Generic** solution for any number of barcodes (slow for very big numbers of barcodes):

```
SELECT x.barcode
     , p.product_id
     , CASE WHEN p.name IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS product_name_exists
FROM (
   SELECT a[i] AS barcode
   FROM  (
      SELECT a.a, generate_series(1, array_upper(a.a, 1)) AS i
      FROM  ( 
         SELECT '{679046,679047,679082,679228,679230,679235,679236,'
                 '679238,679328,679330,679528,679608,679609,679647,'
                 '679727,679728,679730,679808,679809,679828,679830}'::text[] AS a
            ) a
        ) i
    ) x
LEFT   JOIN product USING (barcode);
```

Or chain `SELECT`s with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT x.barcode
      ,p.product_id
      ,CASE WHEN p.name IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS product_name_exists
FROM (
    SELECT           '679046' AS barcode
    UNION ALL SELECT '679047'
    UNION ALL SELECT '679082'
    UNION ALL SELECT '679228'
    UNION ALL SELECT '679230'
    UNION ALL SELECT '679235'
    UNION ALL SELECT '679236'
-- ...
    ) x
LEFT   JOIN product USING (barcode);
```

Use `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`. You don't want to try and eliminate duplicates with every added barcode. That's slow with large numbers. Related:

- [Selecting arrays in nicely printed format in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604169/selecting-arrays-in-nicely-printed-format-in-sql/7604392#7604392)

Comment: SQL error:

ERROR:  function unnest(text[]) does not exist
LINE 4: FROM   (SELECT unnest (
                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @soul: What's the output of `SELECT version();`?

Comment: @soul: see additional solutions for old versions. Consider upgrading if you can!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter... thanks a lot.. wil try out ur solutions

Comment: SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "i"
LINE 7: ...       SELECT a.a, generate_series(1, array_upper(a.a, 1)) i  for this query SELECT x.barcode
      ,p.product_id
      ,CASE WHEN p.name IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS product_name_exists
FROM (
    SELECT a[i] AS barcode
    FROM   (
        SELECT a.a, generate_series(1, array_upper(a.a, 1)) i
        FROM   ( 
            SELECT
            '{679828,679830}'::text[] AS a
            ) a
        ) i
    )x
LEFT   JOIN product USING (barcode);

Comment: @soul: I think I fixed it: 8.2 needs explicit AS for alias: `AS i`. I don't have an 8.2 version to test. It's too old ..

Comment: @soul: That is no problem, in PG use the SQL `COPY` command or the meta-command `\copy` in `psql` terminal client. For mysql look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706093/exporting-mysql-data-into-excel-csv-via-php/7706164#7706164. Please post a separate question for more details.

Comment: I didn't get u how to copy in postgre? can u explain in brief

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4967/discussion-between-erwin-brandstetter-and-soul)