# Select rows based on long list of two columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Say I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "PROPS" (
   "O_TYPE_ID"  UUID NOT NULL,
   "O_ID"       UUID NOT NULL,
   "R_TYPE_ID"  UUID NOT NULL,
   "NAME"       VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   "VALUE"      VARCHAR,

   CONSTRAINT PK_PROPS  PRIMARY KEY ("O_ID", "R_TYPE_ID", "NAME")
    );
```

Now I have a list of lists which is the list I want to use to query Postgres. Meaning I have a list of

```
List((O_ID.type, NAME.type))
```

I want to list all the records which have the combination of these two types, a single list I could use the IN operator, how can I query for list os list values in the above case? A naive implementation would be to do a where with two equal clause and the and operator, but in my case if the list is too huge that would mean too much IO, how do you handle the scenario to handle the list of lists in a very optimized way without too much IO. Using 9.4+ Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many possible ways: pass two arrays, one array of `O_ID`(let's name it `o_id_arr`), one array of `NAME` (let's name it `name_arr`); then unnest in parallel and join:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   (o_id_arr, name_arr) AS t("O_ID", "NAME")
JOIN   "PROPS" p USING ("O_ID", "NAME");
```

The feature of unnesting multiple arrays in parallel was introduced with Postgres 9.4, so should work for you:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836674/unnest-multiple-arrays-in-parallel/27854382#27854382)

Or, especially for big tables and very long lists, create a temporary table, insert your data into it, optionally `ANALYZE` it, then join to it:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp ("O_ID" UUID, "NAME" VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (..., ...), (..., ...);

ANALYZE tmp;

SELECT p.*
FROM   tmp
JOIN   "PROPS" p USING ("O_ID", "NAME")
```

Normally you should have a multicolumn index on `"PROPS" ("O_ID", "NAME")` for performance. But seeing that `"O_ID"` is type `uuid`, the odd PK index on `("O_ID", "R_TYPE_ID", "NAME")` might do the job. Why "odd"? Two UUID and a varchar column seem too bloated for a good PK ...

Related:

- [Display one row per search term, subsitute default if not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117551/display-one-row-per-search-term-subsitute-default-if-not-found/8118448#8118448)
- [Pass array literal to PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138792/pass-array-literal-to-postgresql-function/17139751#17139751)
- [Pass multiple sets or arrays of values to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600567/pass-multiple-sets-or-arrays-of-values-to-a-function/34601242#34601242)

Aside: get rid of those tedious and error-prone double-quoted identifiers. Use legal, lower case identifiers without double-quotes. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Your unquoted constraint name `PK_PROPS` is saved as `pk_props` ...